# Posting data via JQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am facing issue in Posting data using JQuery. It works fine when I do it through Chrome Extension Postman.

**My Code**

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url:                'http://pankajserver.in/api/SaveRoleApi',
    type:               "POST",
    data:               {Role : "wsed"},
    async:              true,
    contentType:        "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "X-Requested-With":   "XMLHttpRequest"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
    debugger;
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    debugger;
});
```

> Url:                http://pankajserver.in/api/SaveRoleApi
>   contentType:        "application/json; charset=utf-8"
>   X-Requested-With:   "XMLHttpRequest"

Works fine when posted data with Postman Chrome Extension. Screenshot below

[image]

Comment: Please the error you see in your console, or the result when you call it using ajax.

Comment: whats the status code showing up in console ??

Comment: When you use an object as the `data:` option, it sends the parameters using `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. It can't send JSON automatically, if you need to do that you need to call `JSON.stringify()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
$.ajax({
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "http://pankajserver.in/api/SaveRoleApi",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
    },
    "data": {
        "Role": "wsed"
    },
    success: function (msg) {
        debugger;
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

I see error in console Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://pankajserver.in/api/SaveRoleApi. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

for that please allow cross origin by placig this code in your root .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

for more info to allow cros origin please refer [this link](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled)

Comment: I got the error: here is the screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zCS1T.png

Comment: Are you trying this code on same domain or please allow cross origin on server and try again

Answer (score 0):

write this headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'} instead of  "X-Requested-With":   "XMLHttpRequest" and dataType: "json" instead of  contentType:        "application/json; charset=utf-8",

```
var request = $.ajax({
 url:                'http://pankajserver.in/api/SaveRoleApi',
 type:               "POST",
 data:               {Role : "wsed"},
 async:              true,
 dataType: "json",
 contentType:        "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
});

request.done(function(msg) {
 debugger;
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
 debugger;
});
```

Comment: Could you please type the correct jquery code in your post? Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: I got the error: here is the screenshot: i.stack.imgur.com/zCS1T.png